# Coinsecure send bitcoin error

Tags: php, bitcoin

If I want to send bitcoin from my wallet to another using coinsecure api, but when I tried to send using bellow code it will give 
me error.

See Here is my request code :

```
$request_parameter = array( "walletID"=> "XXXXXXXXX",
                                "amt"=> 0.00011,
                                "toAddr"=> "XXXX1FXXXu1fdsfdszxcgiJpRoXXdxhG",
                                "msg"=> "This is from coinsecure"
                            );


    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.coinsecure.in/v1/user/wallet/coin/withdraw/initiate');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
    $body = json_encode($request_parameter);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $body);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Authorization:mykey'));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    print_r($result);
    exit;
```

Can you guys please let me know why I am getting error as below :

```
{
  "success": false,
  "count": 1,
  "message": "JsResultException(errors:List((,List(ValidationError(List('message' is undefined on object: {\"walletID\":[\"This field is required\"],\"amt\":[\"This field is required\"],\"toAddr\":[\"This field is required\"]}),WrappedArray())))))",
  "time": 1473426647060,
  "method": "Initiate BTC Withdrawal",
  "title": "/v1/user/wallet/coin/withdraw/initiate"
}
```

Comment: Error is already saying that `undefined on object: {\"walletID\"`   make sure  this parameter is valid.

Comment: @PunitGajjar : Thanks, but See in my request parameter walletId is already available